# Proving an isomorphism without proving that it is Onto

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am a bit perplexed. I understood that to prove an isomorphism:

1. Prove that the group is homomorphic whereby the operation is preserved by showing that  => $\Phi (z \space \circ \space w) = \Phi (z) . \Phi (w)$
2. Prove $\Phi$ is one-to-one
3. Prove $\Phi$ is onto

One book argue (and some others) stipulate that you do not need to prove thatit is onto. I quote "[if you show] that $\Phi$ is an injective homomorphism from [the first Group], then [this Group] is necessarily isomorphic to $\operatorname{im}(\Phi)$"

This last quote is in reference to a question I posted whereby I could not manage to prove that the homomorphism is or not Onto:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2227115?noredirect=1

Comment: Obviously, proving that there is an injective homomorphism $\Phi$ from $G$ into $H$ does not prove that $G \simeq H$ ; however it proves that $G \simeq \mathrm{Im}(\Phi)$ which is a subgroup of $H$.

Comment: Well, if the groups are of the same dimension, it is sufficient to prove one of the two: 1-1 or onto.

Comment: The restriction of a homomorphism to its image is always onto (by definition of the image).

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input. But If an element of the second group H cannot be imaged from the 1st group, is this enough to prove that it is not surjective. Is this statement correct?

Answer (score 3):

It is not saying that the two groups are isomorphic.  It is just saying that the first group is isomorphic to the image of the map.  By definition, the map is onto its image but that image is not necessarily the whole of the second group, it might be a subset / subgroup.

For example, the obvious map from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Q}$ regarded as groups under addition is a homomorphism and one to one.  The image of the map is the integers within $\Bbb{Q}$ which is not all of $\Bbb{Q}$.  So, it has proved that there is a subgroup of $\Bbb{Q}$ isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$ but not that all of $\Bbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your $\Phi$ is trivially onto. The group you're isomorphic with is not $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ but the image $\Phi[C^\ast] = \operatorname{Im}(\Phi)$
which is always a subgroup for any homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Both of you are correct, to prove G is Isomorphic to H you need to show 1.,2.,3. which you have stated for some $\Phi:G\to H$.
The thing is $\operatorname{Im}\Phi\space$ is a subgroup of H and the equality $H=\operatorname{Im}\Phi$ does not necessarily hold when $\Phi$ is a homomorphism.